# Converting nested for loops into recursion (c++)

Tags: c++, recursion

Is there a method to logically convert a nested for loop into a recursive method?

For instance:

```
for(int i=0; i<n*2; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
```

What would be the best method to make this recursive?

Comment: The way to make this recursion-based is to keep it as it is. Do not use recursion here. Or to put it differently, please elaborate your reasons why you think that recursion is needed here or why it could have any advantage.

Comment: @George that's correct. fixed.

Comment: @yuunosch that's very unhelpful. I'm trying to make it recursive for theory's sake.

Comment: Sorry, I really want to help. So you would want this recursion-based, no matter the disadvantages? How much recursion experience do you have. Can you count to 10 in recursion?

Comment: It will be more easy to convert it in recursion if you share the problem. as for recursion, we need a base case to stop the recursion

Comment: @Yunnosch I am capable of emulating a singular for loop with recursion (so yes I can count to 10), but I am lost on how to make nested one recursive.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the best you can do. A recursive counting to 10 (or better to `n`) is quite a good foundation to help you further.

Comment: @foragerDev I am simply trying to emulate this nested for loop as a recursive function and count the iterations using that recursive function. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use recursive here.
But if you're just curious (and supposing, you know about [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)), here's the function:

```
void recursiveFor(int i, int j, int n) {
    if (!(i < n * 2)) {  
        return;
    }

    // Function body.

    if (j + 1 < n) {
        recursiveFor(i, j + 1, n);
    } else {
        recursiveFor(i + 1, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Also, compilers add extra [prologue and epilogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue_and_epilogue) to functions and on the other hand optimize the loops (also most CPUs have loop optimizers such as [Loop Stream Detector](https://www.google.com/?q=Loop+Stream+Detector)), so always try to prefer loops over recursive functions.

Comment: i suppose you want to refer to this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

Comment: I was just fixing the link, but thank you!